# How to merge (or rebase) a branch onto its subbranch in github?

Tags: git, github, merge

I don't have much experience on using Git. In my scenario, we have `master` branch, `newversion` branch, and `hotfix` branch (which is a branch from `newversion`).

Now, since I've checked out the `hotfix` branch, there are several other commits have been made on the `newversion` branch. I want to 'see' those changes in my `hotfix` branch, so that I can work using the latest changes available, so I get the latest changes and/or don't repeat the same fixes.

I have seen [this website](https://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git) that explain about `git rebase`, but unfortunately it explain about merge master branch into a branch, not from a branch into a subbranch. The word `origin`, `master`, and `branch` confuses me, and I'm not sure how to modify the example below on the website to match my requirement.

```
git checkout 7.x-1.x  # Check out the "public" branch 
git pull              # Get the latest version from remote
git checkout -b comment_broken_links_101026  # topical branch
... # do stuff here.. Make commits.. test...
git fetch origin      # Update your repository's origin/ branches from remote repo
git rebase origin/7.x-1.x  # Plop our commits on top of everybody else's
git checkout 7.x-1.x  # Switch to the local tracking branch
git pull              # This won't result in a merge commit
git rebase comment_broken_links_101026  # Pull those commits over to the "public" branch
git push               # Push the public branch back up, with my stuff on the top
```

I'm sure this is just a simple matter, I just still not familiar with Git commands and terminologies. I usually uses Github Desktop, but I'm understand that there are some things that needs terminal, especially for special needs like this. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to merge `newversion` branch commits into `hotfix` branch, then you need following steps to do...

```
git checkout hotfix

git merge newversion
```

the first command will active `hotfix` branch & the second command will merge all the latest commits from `newversion` to `hotfix` branch.

:-)

Comment: Oooh, seems it's not as complicated as I think. Let me try it! Thanks!

Comment: sorry, it wasn't actually my question, but my workmate's question. After I gave her your answer, she forgot to follow me back with the result, and I also forgot to update this question lol. Thanks anyway!